# Visual Studio 2015 constantly locking up using TFS through VPN

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, vpn

Like the title says, I connect to our TFS repo through a VPN, and I'm guessing that's what causes my VS to constantly lock up and get the "Not responding" for a few seconds, usually lasts 5-10 seconds and happens every 30 sec-1 min, depending on what I'm doing.

It's almost unusable at this point. Is there anything I can do to work offline or something, so it stops trying to sync with TFS (assuming this is even the issue)?

I am using resharper, but disabling it doesn't seem to improve things at all.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you by any chance have a design model in your solution? In my case, it was causing the problem and removing it, solved the issue for me.

Comment: That's interesting. I do not, but I'll try unloading any projects I'm not actively working on in case there's something else similar to that that's giving me issues.

Comment: Do you use TFVC or Git source control system?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using TFVC source control system, you can use a [local workspace](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/decide-between-using-local-server-workspace) so that you can work offline easily.

You can quickly begin editing a file when your network connection is unavailable or unreliable. From Solution Explorer you can add, edit, delete, rename, undo, and compare items in your workspace even when you're not connected to your Team Foundation Server.

Comment: I am using a local workspace, but the problem is that I do have network connection. Seems like maybe it's just slow or stutters or something, I'm not really sure what causes the freezes, but it's not that I'm losing connectivity, at least not for more than a few seconds.

Comment: It seems like a network performance issue. It's hard for us to troubleshoot this performance. You may try with another client machine to see whether the issue persists.

Comment: You're certainly right that it is hard to troubleshoot! I don't even really know what the cause is for sure, just kind of making guesses. I don't really know any way to track what's going on to even find out where the issue is. I have tried moving the Visual Studio installation to my SSD, since I thought it might've been a data read issue, but I'm still getting the same results. If I remote into a machine on the network, I don't get that issue, but I do have locks on the remote connection, so I think it has something to do with the VPN connection.